# Can't get Excel VBA Refreshing property

Tags: excel, vba

**Objective**

I want to verify the active refreshing status using the DataFeedConnection.Refreshing property, but I'm getting a '1004' error upon executing the script.

**Background**

I'm running the code below in order to try to verify some of the settings in a file. I'm going to be saving each sheet in the Excel file as an "exported" file in another location upon refresh. However, when I refresh all via macro and close, it will try to close before the file has refreshed.

```
Sub test()

Dim output As String
Dim aw As Workbook
Dim dfc As DataFeedConnection

Set aw = ActiveWorkbook
'Set dfc = ActiveWorkbook.Connections(2).DataFeedConnection

MsgBox (aw.Connections(2).DataFeedConnection.Refreshing)

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple issue. Turns out the type of connection created was an OLEDDB Connection. The property works just fine on that object.

Example:

```
aw.Connections.item(i).OLEDBConnection.Refreshing
```